Route works fine in local Docker container, but throws a stack trace error when deployed to CloudRun
I am working on an app in Python, using Selenium WebDriver (with Chrome / ChromeDriver) for web scraping.
My route works fine in a local Docker container (200, with the expected data returned successfully).
But when I deploy (to Google CloudRun, using the same Docker image I'm running locally) and run the same route, I get this error:
"Message: 
Stacktrace:
#0 0x2a53f7fc886a <unknown>
#1 0x2a53f7c96e50 <unknown>
#2 0x2a53f7ce6644 <unknown>
#3 0x2a53f7ce6931 <unknown>
#4 0x2a53f7d2c534 <unknown>
#5 0x2a53f7d0b4bd <unknown>
#6 0x2a53f7d299c6 <unknown>..."

Here's my Dockerfile:
# Use the Python image from Docker Hub
FROM python:3.12.4-slim

# Set the working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Install system dependencies for Chrome
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    wget \
    unzip \
    gcc \
    g++ \
    make \
    libnss3 \
    libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 \
    libatk-bridge2.0-0 \
    libatk1.0-0 \
    libcups2 \
    libxkbcommon0 \
    libx11-xcb1 \
    libxcomposite1 \
    libxdamage1 \
    libxrandr2 \
    libxshmfence1 \
    libglib2.0-0 \
    libpango-1.0-0 \
    libpangocairo-1.0-0 \
    libfontconfig1 \
    libnss3 \
    fonts-liberation \
    libasound2 \
    libdrm2 \
    libgbm1 \
    libgtk-3-0 \
    libvulkan1 \
    libxfixes3 \
    xdg-utils \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# Install Google Chrome
RUN wget https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb
RUN dpkg -i google-chrome-stable_current_amd64.deb; apt-get -fy install

# Copy dependencies into the container and install
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Copy the rest of the application code into the container
COPY . .

# Expose the port
EXPOSE 8000

# Run the app (with Uvicorn)
CMD ["uvicorn", "app.router:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000", "--reload"]


My Chrome version is 128.0.6613.119
In requirements.txt I have chromedriver-binary>=128.0.0,<129.0.0
Here's the function called by my route:
from selenium import webdriver
import chromedriver_binary

@staticmethod
    async def search_info(company_name: str):
        options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        options.add_argument('--headless')
        options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
        options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
        options.add_argument('--remote-debugging-port=9222') 

        driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
        final_result = []

        try:
            keywords = ["Talent Acquisition", "Recruiter", "HR", "CEO"]
            for keyword in keywords:
                result = searchInfoService._search_info(
                    driver, company_name, keyword
                )
                if result:
                    final_result.extend(result[:1])
            return final_result
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
            raise
        finally:
            driver.quit()


So far, after hours of research, I've tried:



Step
Local (Docker) result
Deployed result




use ChromeDriverManager to install compatible chromedriver: driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeDriverManager().install() options=options)
❌ Error from RUN file
-


updated webdriver_manager to 4.0.2
✅ worked
❌ 503: Service unavailable


increased memory in deployed container
-
❌ 500: Stack trace error


reconfigured Dockerfile to install compatible versions of Chrome & ChromeDriver
✅ worked
❌ 500: Stack trace error


current version: simplified Chrome install, added chromedriver-binary as a dependency (as here and here), updated Selenium to 4.24.0, removed service arg from driver (according to Selenium docs, it’s no longer needed): driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
✅ worked
❌ 500: Stack trace error



I'm totally stumped. If anyone has insight, I'd deeply appreciate it!
I'm a beginner, so please forgive any messiness in the code.

That's not a Python stack trace. Whatever is failing, it's not your code.

Thanks! That's a relief. Any ideas where else I should look?

Taking a wild guess here.
Given it's an async method, if the work is being done with no current in-flight http request then cloud run will kill the container. You have a couple of options.

Configure minimum instances on your service, so there's always at least one service always running. This will mean async stuff can run, useful for development.

Change the deployment mode to CPU is always allocated instead of CPU is only allocated during request processing


There's a good explanation about how that works here. https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/cpu-allocation
Again this is a wild guess based on the information I can see from your post. I've not seen that error before, and I've used Cloud Run for a very long time.
Side note: You also mentioned you bumped the memory, but might I suggest bumping it even further (like just for the sake of ruling it out) to the max it will go. Headless browsers scraping data which is what it appears to be doing can use up a lot of memory, especially chrome.

Thanks so much, I'll try that and update here!
